# TCP client not reading the send half of the message from server

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I have a TCP server which send the data in the below format

```
------------|--------------------------------
---Header---|  ----------- Data ----------
------------|--------------------------------
```

Header is of size 40 bytes of which first 2 bytes signifies the Data length and all the remaining bytes are 0 .

When the size of the data that needs to transfer from the server end is greater than 1500 the server sends the data in the following manner.

```
example:  if length(data) == 1597

  first transaction -> 
   -------|--------------------
   |Header| data of length 1460
   -------|--------------------
  second transaction ->
   |--------------------
   data of length 147 (Note this transaction doesn't have header)
   |--------------------
```

This is the process I'm following to read the data from the server on client end

1. First i read the header (40 bytes) and process this to get the data length to be read.
2. After get the data length i read "data-length" bytes to get the actual data.

The problem I'm facing is that this process works fine in my pc but when i test this other pcs it only works in debug mode (like when i step over each time). Other it only reads the first half of the message and discards the next part and throws this error.

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Exception occurred {0}
  Source=SockTest
  StackTrace:
   at socketTest.sockTest.readData() in C:\usr\testing\SocketTransREcive\SockTest\sockTest.cs:line 125
   at socketTest.main.testTrasRecv(sockTest sock, String command) in C:\usr\testing\SocketTransREcive\SockTest\Program.cs:line 13
   at socketTest.main.testSend() in C:\usr\testing\SocketTransREcive\SockTest\Program.cs:line 51
   at socketTest.main.Main(String[] args) in C:\usr\testing\SocketTransREcive\SockTest\Program.cs:line 63

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    socketTest.sockTest.readData() in sockTest.cs

Inner Exception 1:
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection. (Parameter 'count')
```

I'm not sure what is causing the issue. I have checked the transactions on wire-shark and it seems server is sending them properly. Any help would be really appreciated!

**Client Code**

```
namespace socketTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    public class sockTest : IDisposable
    {
        // defaults
        private string ip = "192.168.1.100";
        private int port = 1234;
        //private int port = 16666;
        public int error = -1;
        public int noError = 0;
        bool disposed = false;
        private byte[] buffer;
        private byte[] header;
        // updated once instanciated 
        private IPAddress Ip;
        public TcpClient socketHandle;
        public NetworkStream tcpStream;
        // instance check 
        private static readonly Lazy<sockTest> lazy = new Lazy<sockTest>(() => new sockTest());

        private sockTest()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Program started !");
                this.Ip = IPAddress.Parse(ip);

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //throw new Exception("Could not initialize socket erro : {0}", exception);
                Console.WriteLine("Could not initialize socket error: {0}", exception);
            }
        }

        public static sockTest Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return lazy.Value;
            }
        }

        public int connect()
        {
            try
            {
                this.socketHandle = new TcpClient();
                this.buffer = new byte[4000];
                this.header = new byte[10];
                this.socketHandle.Connect(this.Ip, this.port);
                this.tcpStream = socketHandle.GetStream();
                return noError;
            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                return error;
            }

        }

        public int prcessHeader(byte[] header)
        {
            int ind = 0;
            int flag = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 2)
            {
                int value = (header[i + 0]) | (header[i + 1] << 8);
                if(flag == 0)
                {
                  
                    ind = value;
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }

            return ind;
        }

        public string readData()
        {
            try
            {
                tcpStream.Read(this.header, 0, 10);
                var inputString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this.header);
                //int msg_len = Int32.Parse(inputString);
                int msg_len = prcessHeader(this.header);
                tcpStream.Read(this.buffer, 0, msg_len);
                return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this.buffer);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception occurred {0}", exception);
                //return null;
            }
        }



        public int sendData(string data)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                tcpStream.Write(bData, 0, bData.Length * sizeof(byte));
                return noError;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return error;
            }
        }

        public void closeConnection()
        {
            tcpStream.Close();
            this.socketHandle.Close();

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Dispose of unmanaged resources.
            this.CheckDispose(true);
            // Suppress finalization.
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void CheckDispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposed)
                return;

            if (disposing)
            {
                this.closeConnection();
            }

            disposed = true;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: `NetworkStream.Read` returns a value that tells you how many bytes it was able to obtain. It can return as little as *1* byte from each successful call, and it's up to you to loop to fill a buffer if you know you want more bytes than it has current returned.

Comment: TCP doesn't preserve boundaries between sends and reads as discrete messages.  It's all just a stream of bytes, like marbles being put into a tube - each byte is a marble.  The reader doesn't know how many bytes "at a time" were sent by the sender.  Even your header with the size in it may arrive partially, separated across multiple Read calls - even if it were transmitted with a single Send call.

Comment: seems like a interesting thing how do we handle this case, could you point me out to a resource or something .Happy to learn !.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the implementation of the comment

```
public string readData()
        {
            try
            {
                string tempRecv = "";
                int len_read_msg = 0;
                tcpStream.Read(this.header, 0, 10);
// your header parsing logic 
                int msg_len = processHeader(this.header);
                if (msg_len > 1024)
                {
                    len_read_msg = 1024;
                }
                else
                {
                    len_read_msg = msg_len;
                }
                int tempRead = 0;
                int compRead = 0;
                while (compRead < msg_len)
                {
                    Array.Clear(this.buffer, 0, this.buffer.Length);
                    tempRead = tcpStream.Read(this.buffer, 0, len_read_msg);
                    compRead = compRead + tempRead;
                    len_read_msg = msg_len - compRead;
                    var encoded = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this.buffer).Trim();

                }
                return tempRecv;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //throw new Exception("Exception occurred {0}", exception);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Cheers!